# How to auto-detect screen size in Android using playn?

Tags: android, playn

I have recently noticed that layers can be resized when needed, so I'm trying to implement a method to resize the main layer to the size of the android screen where it is running.

How do I access to the device screen size from playn?

And there is another way to adjust the size of the game in android devices depending on the size of the screen with playn?

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you are looking for is `PlayN.graphics().screenHeight()` and `PlayN.graphics().screenWidth()`.

Copied out of the Graphics.java file:

- screenWidth() - Gets the width of the available screen real-estate, in pixels.
- screenHeight() - Gets the height of the available screen real-estate, in pixels.
- width() - Gets the width of the drawable surface, in pixels.
- height() - Gets the height of the drawable surface, in pixels.

As the descriptions state, screenHeight() and screenWidth() provide the actual screen height/width. With these values, you can adjust the size or scale of your game to fit the screen.

Answer (score 1):

`PlayN.graphics().width()` and `PlayN.graphics().height()` give you the view size that you *requested* (via `PlayN.graphics().setSize()`), not the maximum available screen size.

To obtain the maximum available screen size, use `PlayN.graphics().availableWidth()` and `PlayN.graphics().availableHeight()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

This gives you the available device rendering surface.

```
PlayN.graphics().width()
PlayN.graphics().height()
```

Or I missunderstood your problem?